# MVC model binding - how to pass a List as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC questionnaire app that loops through a set of questions

```
<% foreach (var question in Model.CriteriaQuestionList)
   { %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>           
        <%= Html.Encode(question.Description)%>           
    </legend>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
```

I want to submit a list of text responses for each question using model binding and was thinking of this approach

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ChampionCriteria", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "themeform" }))
   { %>
<%  int i = -1; //index %>
<% foreach (var question in Model.CriteriaQuestionList)
   { %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <% i = i + 1; %>
        <%= Html.Encode(question.Description)%>
        <input name="[<%=i%>].freeTextResponse" class="textarea" type="text" id="text<%=i%>" />
    </legend>
</fieldset>
<%} %>
```

So this view can submit a List<> of question responses using model binding.

Can I use html.textboxfor with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for model biding of list. If you have variable length you can have look [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). You may also look at [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/simpleList.html) for another way of doing it.

Comment: +1 - the sanderson one would be a good fit in the OP's case i think

Comment: OK thanks.    However for a way forward I need to be able to use HTML.TextBoxFor and HiddenFor so I can use server side validation.   I do not want to use Javascript.